# Generate string of zeros of random length

Tags: php

I'm trying to  generate a random string of zeros

like this: 00 or 00000000 or 0000 between a certain length

how do I generate zeros and output it as a variable

Answer (score 6):

You can try with [str_repeat](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php) :

From 0 to 9 zeros :

```
echo str_repeat("0", rand(0, 9));
```

From 5 to 14 :

```
echo str_repeat("0", rand(5, 14));
```

And so on.

Answer (score 0):

this will spit out between 1 and 10 zeroes:

```
$start = 1;
$end = 10;

$str = "";

$number_of_zeroes = rand($start, $end);

for ($i = 0; $i < $number_of_zeroes; $i++) {
    $str .= "0";
}

echo $str;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$len = mt_rand(1,99);
$foo = str_pad($input, $len, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```